# CSS for three column display

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I want to create the following three column layout. The middle column will be of variable size and be centered. The left and right column will grow or shrink to meet the edge of the middle column and the edge of the outer parent div. It should look like this.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| Size: X        |     Variable Size   |           Size: X  |          
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried a few different methods but none have worked.

EDIT: To clarify I'm trying to achieve the effect of a header that is centered with two horizontal lines on either side of the text.

https://css-tricks.com/line-on-sides-headers/

I wanted to see if it was possible to do with three nested divs.

Comment: Can you show us your code so far? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Container div `display:table`, child div `disable:table-cell`

Comment: "*none have worked.*" - where, and how, did they fail?

Comment: other solution: padding on the left and right side, position absolute for the left and right cols and position relative on parent, box-sizing of the middle col on broder-box and width on 100%, realize it with div-elements

Comment: Here is your solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824789/proper-way-to-achieve-3-column-layout-with-fluid-center

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple different methods you could take. Actually, 5 that I can think of.

For the next few examples, the markup is this:

```
<div class="container">
    <aside class="fixed column"></aside>
    <main class="fluid column"></main>
    <aside class="fixed column"></aside>
</div>
```

Global CSS

```
.fixed {
    width: 100px;
}
.fluid {
    calc(100% - 200px); /* subtract total fixed width of the sidebars */
}
```

Flexbox:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
}
.container .column {
    flex: 0 1 1;
}
```

Float:

```
.container:after {
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
.container .column {
    float: left;
}
```

Table:

```
.container {
    display: table;
}
.container .column {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Inline-Block:

```
.container .column {
    display: inline-block;
}
.container .column:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: -4px;
}
```

Absolute:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}
.container .column {
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.container .fluid {
    left: 100px; /* width of 1 fixed sidebar */
}
.container .fixed:last-child {
    right: 0;
}
```

Here's a link to the codepen :)
http://codepen.io/akwright/pen/OPvwLv

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td width="20%">COLUMN 1</td>
      <td width="*">COLUMN 2</td>
      <td width="20%">COLUMN 3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't use tables if you don't really have a table... tables are so ugly, better use divs and give them table-displays...

Comment: Nate draw a table in his question. If he prefers to use bootstrap for example I can show him how to do just that using boostrap grid.

Answer (score 0):

Just use display table and table-cell. 
Don't use actual tables unless you have tabular data, it is not a best practice and hard to make responsive.

```css
        .table{
            display:table;
            width:100%;
        }
        .table-cell{
            display: table-cell;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .cell1{
            background-color: red;
        }

        .cell3{
            background-color: blue;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="table">
        <div class="table-cell cell1">123</div>
        <div class="table-cell cell2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut </div>
        <div class="table-cell cell3">321</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.table{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 25px auto;
    border-top: 1px dashed #222;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #222;
}
.table > div{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;   
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    border-right: 1px dashed #222;
}
.table > div:nth-child(1){
    border-left: 1px dashed #222;
}
.table > div:nth-child(1),
.table > div:nth-child(3){
    width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div>cell</div>
    <div>cell</div>
    <div>cell</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to

> The left and right column will grow or shrink to meet the edge of the
>   middle column and the edge of the outer parent div.

You simply want to have each column in `%` . The easiest way to do seems to be :

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<style>
.side {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
}
.middle {
  width: 60%; 
  float: left;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="side">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="middle">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="side">&nbsp;</div>
</body>
</html>
```